# Contradictory protocol conformances

Tags: swift, protocols, swift5

Can anybody explain please, what is going on here:

```
struct Test {
    var value: Int
}

// -----------------------------------
protocol Test1: Equatable {
    var value: Int { get set }
}
extension Test1 {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.value == rhs.value + 1
    }
}
// -----------------------------------
protocol Test2: Equatable {
    var value: Int { get set }
}
extension Test2 {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.value == rhs.value + 2
    }
}
// -----------------------------------

extension Test: Test1 {}
extension Test: Test2 {}

let a = Test(value: 5)
let b = Test(value: 5)

print(a == b) // true, which is unexpected
```

If conforms only to `Test1` or only to `Test2` it works as expected.
Conforming to `Test1` and `Test2`. At first I thought that the order will matter. But looks like it just cancels each other! Without any warnings. Which is very counterintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** `Test` conforms to `Equatable` *not* because of the two extensions you provided, but because of the auto-generated `Equatable` implementation. As you said, if there were only those two extensions, it would be ambiguous which `==` is the `Equatable` implementation.

Neither of the `==` in the `Test1` or `Test2` protocol extensions are called. Instead, the auto-generated `Equatable` implementation is called. As you may recall, a `==` operator is auto-generated for types whose properties are all `Equatable`, and is declared to conform to `Equatable` itself.

This is because members declared in extensions use static binding, so when there are multiple versions of the same member available, the version declared in the extension will only be chosen if the compile time type is the extension's type. For example:

```
protocol P { }
class C : P { func f() { print("C") } }
extension P { func f() { print("P") } }
C().f() // C
(C() as P).f() // P
```

In `a == b`, both `a` and `b` are `Test`, so none of the extension operators gets chosen. However, since `Test1` and `Test2` both use `Self`, you can only use them as generic constraints, and can't cast to them either. Therefore, I don't think you will be able to call the `==` declared in the extensions at all.

Anyway, if you want to see an error message saying that there are duplicate `==` operators available:

```
struct Test {
    var value: Int
    var x: Any? // now there is no auto-generated Equatable implementation!
}
```

> error: type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable' extension
> Test: Test1 {} ^
>
> note: candidate exactly matches
>
> ```
>    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
>                ^
> ```
>
> note: candidate exactly matches
>
> ```
>    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
>                ^
> ```

If you remove one of the extensions, then `Test` conforms to `Equatable` *because of the extension*, as there is no more ambiguity. Therefore, the auto-generated implementation isn't auto-generated anymore, and there is only one `==` to choose from - the one declared in the extension.

Comment: "Therefore, I don't think you will be able to call the == declared in the extensions at all." As I've mentioned in the post, if choose only one extension, == of that extension IS called.

Comment: @Roman Yes of course. I meant "you can't call either of them **if you keep both extensions**". I explained why in my comment reply to Roman Ryzhiy.

Comment: @Roman I have moved the contents of that comment into the answer. Please check. Does it make sense?